# How to include third party JARs in Android library, AAR, without merging code

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library, aar

I got a new requirement to include a JAR file `myspecial.jar` into a Android library I am building. When I build the AAR using gradle, the resulting bundle has both my classes and classes from `myspecial.jar` into one file called, `classes.jar`. I want to keep them separated.

According to Android's website, https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html , it is possible to do that.

> Additionally, an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries:
>
> /assets/
>
> /libs/name.jar
>
> /jni/abi_name/name.so
>
> /proguard.txt
>
> /lint.jar

I have tried all the limited gradle-fu I know of. I can't figure it out.

I came across this: https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar but it doesn't seem to work for me.

TL;DR: Need gradle support to bundle third party jar as its own file in libs directory inside aar without being compiled alongside my own code into `classes.jar`.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am looking for the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am still looking around for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you disable proguard, by default they are separated.
change `minifyEnabled true` to `minifyEnabled false` could disable the proguard.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to migrate to Gradle plugin 3.0 - https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html.  It offers `api` and `implementation` properties that eliminate duplicated classes in jars and aars.